# Salvar inputs com arrays com PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma tabela gerada dinamicamente onde insiro varios produtos. Estou tentando usar um for para salvar esses produtos, mas se tenho apenas um produto já não dá certo, precisa ter mais de um. Tentei com foreach mas não deu certo.

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('storeProduct') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table m-0" id="products-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Produto/Serviço</th>
                                <th>Quantidade</th>
                                <th>Valor Unitário</th>
                                <th>Valor Total</th>
                                <th>Remover</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="row">

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5" onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>    
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Incluir Orçamento</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection

@push('js')
<script>

RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
        tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
};

AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td class="col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control product" name="name[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="unit_price[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total"><input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total_price[]"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2">';
    cols += '<button class="btn btn-danger waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#products-table").append(newRow);

    $(".amount, .price").unbind('blur keyup');
    $(".amount, .price").on("blur keyup",function(){
        const tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        const quant = parseInt(tr.find('.amount').val());
        const valor = parseInt(tr.find('.price').val());
        var total = quant * valor;

        if (!isNaN(quant) && !isNaN(valor)){
            tr.find('.total').html('<input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total_price[]" value=" '+total+' ">');
        }
    });

    return false;
};

</script>
@endpush
```

$request:

```
array:5 [▼
   "_token" => "wLRaFmgHxEMtOzPMzzylPFjtJLawgr262kOz4xGf"
   "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Produto 1"
    1 => "Produto 1"
   ]
  "amount" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
  ]
  "unit_price" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "200"
    1 => "300"
   ]
   "total_price" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "400"
   1 => "900"
   ]
]
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{

private $product;

public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->all()); $i++) { 
        $this->product = new Product();
        $this->product->name = $request->name[$i];
        $this->product->amount = $request->amount[$i];
        $this->product->unit_price = $request->unit_price[$i];
        $this->product->total_price = $request->total_price[$i];
        $this->product->save();
    }        
}

}
```

Comment: No controller use `for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->name); $i++)`

Comment: Sim, acabei conseguindo colocando dessa forma que falou. Mas será que essa é a melhor forma para fazer isso? Não teria alguma forma de fazer sem ter que conhecer o nome do campo?

Comment: A melhor não é usar `<input name="total_price[]">`, mas sim `<input name="product[1][total_price]">` onde esse indice 1 é inserido dinamicamente pelo javascript. Quando for no loop use `foreach()` ao invés de `for()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente existe uma maneira simples é utilizando o método `create` passando o `array` para armazena os dados, e lembrando que a sua classe Product deve estar configurado o seu `fillable` da seguinte forma:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','amount','unit_price','total_price'];
}
```

e no método:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->name); $i++) 
    { 
         $this->product->create([
                    'name' => $request->name[$i],
                    'amount' => $request->amount[$i] ,
                    'unit_price' => $request->amount[$i],
                    'total_price' => $request->total_price[$i]
         ]);
    } 
}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** no seu método `store` tinha uma linha: `$this->product = new Product();` isso não pode acontecer, porque, se está recriando uma instância que já foi setada pelo ***construtor***. Se por venturar quiser daquele jeito utilize, então assim: `$product = new Product();` e prossiga com aqueles comandos.</sub>

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [The Create Method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)
- [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment)